# Can I "stop" a LINQ method chain midway?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following method-chain in my code:

```
MyFormCollection
    .Select(form => Handler.HandleForm(form))
    .Select(form =>
    {
        form.Id = Guid.Empty;
        form.OtherProperty = existingValue;
        return form;
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(FormService.SaveForm);
```

The issue with this code is that `Handler.HandleForm()` can return null in certain cases. If that is the case, I want to skip the rest of the methods for that form and just continue with the next item in the list.

Is there any way to do this without doing a null-check in every step?

Comment: `.Where(form => form != null)`? In order *filter out* `null`s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest adding `Where`:

```
MyFormCollection
    .Select(form => Handler.HandleForm(form))
    .Where(form => form != null) // <- from this line on not null form(s) only
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach would be to simplify your query by adding everything into .ForEach:

```
MyFormCollection.ToList()
    .ForEach(form => {
        if((form = Handler.HandleForm(form)) != null)
        {
           form.Id = Guid.Empty;
           form.OtherProperty = existingValue;
           FormService.SaveForm(f))
        }
     }
```